# How do I implement an 8pt grid system? What is the difference in implementing a hard and soft grid?

Tags: user-experience

I'm looking out for possibilities of implementing 8pt grid system using sketch or adobe XD.

Answer (score 2):

In general, 8pt grids are great because they are easily divisible. Half of 8 is 4, half of that is 2, and so on. A generic 10pt grid fails pretty quickly here. This divisibility helps in converting to rems, ems, etc.

A grid is fantastic to get in the habit of using because it keeps your components easy to use together, creates reusability when moving to code, standards are easier to learn than unique rules for everything... and the benefits keep going.

> In short, Hard grids snap content to a fixed grid, and Soft grids define the spacing between elements rather than to some looming, document-wide grid.

From *[iOS: Hard & Soft 8-point grids](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-hard-soft-8-point-grids-6d2d1dc2fcf7#:%7E:text=In%20short%2C%20Hard%20grids%20snap,a%20specific%20context%20or%20task.)*

Most of my work falls more in the soft grid camp where the spacing is a set of guidelines that are relative, i.e. all 's are a line-height of 24px and have a spacing beneath them of 16px.

There are so many articles that answer this better than I can here, so here are a few for reading:

- [The Comprehensive 8pt Grid Guide](https://medium.com/swlh/the-comprehensive-8pt-grid-guide-aa16ff402179)
- [Design System based on the 8pt Grid](https://medium.com/swlh/design-system-based-on-the-8pt-grid-2473ca5f0ae1)
- [The 8pt Grid: Consistent Spacing in UI Design with Sketch](https://blog.prototypr.io/the-8pt-grid-consistent-spacing-in-ui-design-with-sketch-577e4f0fd520)